# Community user's RSS feed is a 404

Tags: bug, community-user, feed, activity

Recreation steps:

1. Go to "Community" moderator (user -1) user page on the Security Stack Exchange: https://security.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community
2. Click "Activity"
3. Click "[user feed](https://security.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/-1)"
4. 404!

NB: Have tested on other users, works fine for other users. Haven't tested on stack exchanges other than security.

Expected behaviour:

I suppose a valid 200 response with a blank RSS feed

Comment: Repro-ed here on MSE as well.Could be [meta-tag:status-bydesign] given that the community user is special.

Comment: Maybe it is disabled on purpose as community can have a rather high number of activities causing a performance hit on the db when the feed is requested.

Comment: The bot only votes though, and the RSS feed doesn't include votes.

Comment: @Jansky it takes the edits from anonymous users as well.

Comment: The bot never vote, it owns votes of deleted accounts. However, the "bot" also have actual posts on meta sites, e.g. https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1862/2015-community-moderator-election